# Webfonts not displaying on Nexus 7 when using % instead of px

Tags: ipad, responsive-design, percentage, pixel, nexus-7

I have consistently noticed the Nexus 7 will not render a webfont if it's containing element has been sized using percentages instead pixels.

As you can imagine, this is very bad news for responsive design. The odd thing is that on my android phone, using the same browser(Chrome), the webfonts appear fine.

Has anyone else ran into this problem?

****UPDATE**********

I wanted to test this theory, so I created a testing page with three divs - one sized using pixels, one sized using percentages and the last sized using ems. The webfonts appeared in all three divs without issue. On my site however, when I toggle a div's size from percentage to pixels it is still causing this issue. It seems this alone is not the problem. I'm going to continue testing with more nested divs, but if any of you want to experiment yourselves, here's the link:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46736730/nexus-test/nexus-test.html

ANY ideas/insight would be really helpful!